# Align textbox after dynamic labels

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < gBoxes.Length; i++)
        {
            var LabelID = new Label();
            gLabels[i] = LabelID;
            LabelID.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 7.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            LabelID.Name = "label" + i;
            LabelID.Text = gColumns[i];
            LabelID.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, StartLoc);
            this.Controls.Add(LabelID);
            iPanel.Controls.Add(LabelID);

            var BoxID = new TextBox();
            gBoxes[i] = BoxID;
            BoxID.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 7.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            BoxID.Name = "textbox" + i;
            BoxID.Text = gContent[i];
            BoxID.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, StartLoc);
            BoxID.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 19);
            this.Controls.Add(BoxID);
            iPanel.Controls.Add(BoxID);

            StartLoc += 25;
        }
```

Which works fine, however, the labels overlap the boxes. Which would be the best method to place the boxes after the labels, and that the boxes are aligned together.

Result:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Label.AutoSize` property to `true`.  (The default value when adding them in the designer is `true` but the default when adding by code is `false`.)  Also set your `TextBox.Location` to have a larger `x` value than your label... you have the starting location of label and textbox at the same `x` value of `12`.

You can also use the `AutoSize` property to determine how wide the labels are and then place the textboxes accordingly.  Add your labels with `AutoSize = true`.  Arrange the text boxes by determining the widest label and resetting the `TextBox.Location` just to the right of them.  Here is an example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int YPos { get; set; }
    List<string> Labels = new List<string>();
    List<Label> LabelControls = new List<Label>();
    List<TextBox> TextBoxControls = new List<TextBox>();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AddRow("medium string", "medium");
        AddRow("This is a longer string", "long");
        AddRow("l", "little");

        Arrange();
    }


    void AddRow(string label, string value)
    {
        Labels.Add(label);

        var LabelID = new Label();
        LabelID.AutoSize = true; // make sure to enable AutoSize
        LabelID.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 7.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        LabelID.Name = "label" + Labels.Count;
        LabelID.Text = label;
        LabelID.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, YPos);
        this.Controls.Add(LabelID);
        panel1.Controls.Add(LabelID);
        LabelControls.Add(LabelID);

        var BoxID = new TextBox();
        BoxID.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 7.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        BoxID.Name = "textbox" + Labels.Count;
        BoxID.Text = value;
        BoxID.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, YPos);
        BoxID.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 19);
        this.Controls.Add(BoxID);
        panel1.Controls.Add(BoxID);
        TextBoxControls.Add(BoxID);

        // both controls have the same Y location
        // and initially will have the same X location
        YPos += 25;
    }

    void Arrange()
    {
        // determine the widest label sized by the AutoSize 
        int maxLabelX = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Labels.Count; i++)
        {
            maxLabelX = Math.Max(maxLabelX, LabelControls[i].Location.X + LabelControls[i].Size.Width);
        }

        // move all the text boxes a little to the right of the widest label
        for (int i = 0; i < Labels.Count; i++)
        {
            TextBoxControls[i].Location = new Point(maxLabelX + 10, TextBoxControls[i].Location.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code generates properly placed `TextBox` controls:

[image: auto-positioned]

Comment: Thanks but not exactly what I'm looking for. All of the labels text are dynamically loaded from SQL. So one label could be 1 letter, others 50+ letters, so I need the boxes to be aligned after the longest label.

Comment: @user1667191 I edited the post to add auto-arranging according to label length